# Making my own message board and displaying posts with php?

Tags: php, forum

First of all check out this example of how I want it to look,

**LOGIN**

Email: aa@aa.aa
Password: aaaaaa

And go to this page http://www.nomomon.com/forums.php?email=aa@aa.aa&v=21828

You see the replies how they indent one another, that is how I want it to look, and now my efforts;

First I have everything set up and a working message board, just not displaying the post replies properly, each post has a parent post ID etc...

Here is my attempt, which works for the first reply but does not iterate like the given example for each post reply with the correct parentID?

```
while ($post = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<p class="spacerTop"><a href="http://www.example.com/boards?topic=' . $_GET['topic'] . '&amp;view=' . $post['postID'] . '">' . $post['subject'] . '</a> - <a href="http://www.example.com/viewaccount?id=' . $post['posterID'] . '">' . $post['username'] . '</a></p>';
    $q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT boardposts.*, accounts.username FROM boardposts INNER JOIN accounts WHERE boardposts.posterID = accounts.id AND boardposts.parentID = ?");
    $q -> execute(array($post['postID']));
    while ($post2 = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          echo '<p class="spacerTop" style="margin: 0 0 0 20px;"><a href="http://www.example.com/boards?topic=' . $_GET['topic'] . '&amp;view=' . $post2['postID'] . '">' . $post2['subject'] . '</a> - <a href="http://www.example.com/viewaccount?id=' . $post2['posterID'] . '">' . $post2['username'] . '</a></p>';
          $q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT boardposts.*, accounts.username FROM boardposts INNER JOIN accounts WHERE boardposts.posterID = accounts.id AND boardposts.parentID = ?");
          $q -> execute(array($post2['postID']));
          while ($post3 = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo '<p class="spacerTop" style="margin: 0 0 0 40px;"><a href="http://www.example.com/boards?topic=' . $_GET['topic'] . '&amp;view=' . $post3['postID'] . '">' . $post3['subject'] . '</a> - <a href="http://www.example.com/viewaccount?id=' . $post3['posterID'] . '">' . $post3['username'] . '</a></p>';
          }
    }
}
```

My first thought was to display each post with the parent ID, then another while loop for those replies and finally another while loop, but it doesn't work the way I want it to as it only shows the replies for the first reply.

Comment: Please take in consideration [this post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/10/the-gamification.html) when you design the layout.

Comment: this is the worst example of spaghetti code I've ever seen. Got dazzled.

Comment: Hey it is a draft and can you help bud?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you're eventually going to have to rethink that function (unless you only want to display at most 3 responses). It will be tempting to do it recursively (because recursion lends itself to this type of problem), but there is a way to do it without recursion that works just as well. Anyways, now that's out of the way, on to why its not working right. Your code seems to be sound but are you sure that SQL query is returning the correct results? Have you tried it without the PHP, just by executing the query and seeing what you get? Not entirely sure if that INNER JOIN is required either.

```
SELECT `postID`, `topic`, `subject`, `posterID`,`username`, `id`
FROM `boardposts`, `account`
WHERE `boardposts`.`posterID` = `accounts`.`id` AND `boardposts`.`parentID` = ?
```

I can't remember but you might have to use table names as well in the select clause (like you are doing now), though i feel as if they might b optional. In any case, make sure your query is returning correct results first.

Comment: Yes the inner join is required as I store the poster's ID not username, so join poster's ID with account ID to grab the username.